# Curl OpenSSL error 141A318A tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Tags: php, curl, https, openssl

I have a webapplication that makes a curl call to a different site to get data.
Since my webspace provider (ionos) made some changes to the server, the curl call is no longer working.

my curl call looked like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$sResult = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It didnt work. $sResult was empty.
I changed my code and tried

```
$test = file_get_contents($link);
```

this gives me the error:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small
```

is there something missing in my curl call or file_get_contents call?

Comment: The certificates for the target server either need to be improved or you must somehow configure openssl to allow dh keys that are too small. I'm not a PHP guy so that's the best I can tell you. It could be that changing the settings system wide will work but it isn't super secure. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233186/ubuntu-20-04-how-to-set-lower-ssl-security-level

Answer (score 31):

The usual recommendation for this error is to set the "CipherString" parameter in /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf to "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=1".

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1233456
- https://imlc.me/dh-key-too-small

In PHP, you can achieve the same thing with [`curl_setopt()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1');
```

This is a better solution than editing openssl.cnf since it allows you to relax security for just one specific call, rather than system-wide.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using the file_get_contents() function, this works nicely

```
$context=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        'ciphers' => 'DEFAULT:!DH'
    ),
); 

$json = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($context));
```

Answer (score 5):

### I was getting this error on the curl command line.

**curl request**

```
curl -k 
     --request POST 
     --url 'https://abc.com.pk/token/api?grant_type=client_credentials' 
     --header 'Authorization: Basic a0NiZXNMTXFlJBY1lBQjJINmtqWVFh' 
     --ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

**Solution:**

```
--ciphers DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
```

Answer (score 1):

To work around that problem, the legacy cipher suites must be enabled by:

`update-crypto-policies --set LEGACY`